# PixiOverlay on leaflet, cant add another image because it is already had an entry

Tags: javascript, leaflet, pixi.js

I'm using Pixi with PixiOverlay on leaflet. I have the following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o70kzxw1/5/) for a dummy simulation. The objective: once you click Add Image 2 - it adds a picture of a hamster randomly on the map.

It (almost) work.

**the problem:**

Error message: `"BaseTexture added to the cache with an id [hamster] that already had an entry"`

I couldn't figure our where to put the loader and how to integrate it properly in terms of code organization: (do I need to use it only once?) what if I have other layers to add?  So I assume my challenge is here:

```
this.loader.load((loader, resources) => {...}
```

Minor: how to reduce the size of the hamster :-)

[image]

my JS code (also on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o70kzxw1/5/))

```
class Simulation
{
    constructor()
    {
          // center of the map
    var center = [1.8650,  51.2094];

    // Create the map
    this.map = L.map('map').setView(center, 2);

    // Set up the OSM layer
    L.tileLayer(
      'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18
      }).addTo(this.map);
    
    this.imagesLayer = new L.layerGroup(); 
    this.imagesLayer.addTo(this.map);
    
    
}

_getRandomCoord()
{
        var randLat = Math.floor(Math.random() * 90);
        randLat *=  Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1;

    var randLon = Math.floor(Math.random() * 180);
    randLon *=  Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1;
    
    return [randLat,randLon]
}

addImage2()
{
                
    this.loader = new PIXI.Loader()
    this.loader.add('hamster', 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/196/196817.png')
    this.loader.load((loader, resources) => {
    
        let markerTexture = resources.hamster.texture
        let markerLatLng = this._getRandomCoord()
        let marker = new PIXI.Sprite(markerTexture)
        marker.anchor.set(0.5, 1)

        let pixiContainer = new PIXI.Container()
        pixiContainer.addChild(marker)

        let firstDraw = true
        let prevZoom

        let pixiOverlay = L.pixiOverlay(utils => {
          let zoom = utils.getMap().getZoom()
          let container = utils.getContainer()
          let renderer = utils.getRenderer()
          let project = utils.latLngToLayerPoint
          let scale = utils.getScale()

          if (firstDraw) {
            let markerCoords = project(markerLatLng)
            marker.x = markerCoords.x
            marker.y = markerCoords.y
          }

          if (firstDraw || prevZoom !== zoom) {
            marker.scale.set(1 / scale)
          }

          firstDraw = true
          prevZoom = zoom
          renderer.render(container)
        }, pixiContainer)

        this.imagesLayer.addLayer(pixiOverlay);
  })
}   

addTriangle()
{
            console.log("Trinalge")   
    var polygonLatLngs = [
        [51.509, -0.08],
        [51.503, -0.06],
        [51.51, -15.047],
        [21.509, -0.08]
    ];
    var projectedPolygon;
    var triangle = new PIXI.Graphics();

    var pixiContainer = new PIXI.Container();
    pixiContainer.addChild(triangle);

    var firstDraw = true;
    var prevZoom;

    var pixiOverlay = L.pixiOverlay(function(utils) {
        var zoom = utils.getMap().getZoom();
        var container = utils.getContainer();
        var renderer = utils.getRenderer();
        var project = utils.latLngToLayerPoint;
        var scale = utils.getScale();

        if (firstDraw) {
            projectedPolygon = polygonLatLngs.map(function(coords) {return project(coords);});
        }
        if (firstDraw || prevZoom !== zoom) {
            triangle.clear();
            triangle.lineStyle(3 / scale, 0x3388ff, 1);
            triangle.beginFill(0x3388ff, 0.2);
            projectedPolygon.forEach(function(coords, index) {
                if (index == 0) triangle.moveTo(coords.x, coords.y);
                else triangle.lineTo(coords.x, coords.y);
            });
            triangle.endFill();
        }
        firstDraw = false;
        prevZoom = zoom;
        renderer.render(container);
    }.bind(this), pixiContainer);
    
            this.imagesLayer.addLayer(pixiOverlay)
}
    
removeLayer()
{
            this.imagesLayer.clearLayers();
}   
}

var simulation = new Simulation();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TLDR: Updated jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gbsdfm97/

more info below:

## First problem: loading resources (textures)

There was error in console because you loaded hamster image on each click:

```
    addImage2()
    {
                    
        this.loader = new PIXI.Loader()
        this.loader.add('hamster', 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/196/196817.png')
        this.loader.load((loader, resources) => {
        ...
```

Better approach is to load image (resource) once at beginning and then just reuse what is loaded in memory:

```
    constructor()
    {
...
        
        this.markerTexture = null;
        this._loadPixiResources();
    }
    
...
    
    _loadPixiResources()
    {
        this.loader = new PIXI.Loader()
        this.loader.add('hamster', 'https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/196/196817.png')
        this.loader.load((loader, resources) => {
            this.markerTexture = resources.hamster.texture;
      })
    }

...
    
    addImage2()
    {
        ...
        let marker = new PIXI.Sprite(this.markerTexture);
```

## Second problem: size of hamsters :)

Scale was set like this:

```
marker.scale.set(1 / scale)
```

Which was too big - so changed it to:

```
// affects size of hamsters:
this.scaleFactor = 0.05;
...
marker.scale.set(this.scaleFactor / scale);
```

Scale of hamsters (not triangles!) is now updated when zoom changes - so when user uses mouse scroll wheel etc.

## Third problem: too many layers in pixiOverlay

Previously on each click on `Add Image 2` or `Add Triangle` button there was added new `pixiContainer` and new `pixiOverlay` which was added as new layer: `this.imagesLayer.addLayer(pixiOverlay);`

New version is a bit simplified: there is only one `pixiContainer` and one `pixiOverlay` created at beginning:

```
    constructor()
    {
        ...
        
        // Create one Pixi container for pixiOverlay in which we will keep hamsters and triangles:
        this.pixiContainer = new PIXI.Container();
        
        let prevZoom;
        
        // Create one pixiOverlay:
        this.pixiOverlay = L.pixiOverlay((utils, data) => {
          ...
        }, this.pixiContainer)

        this.imagesLayer.addLayer(this.pixiOverlay);
    }
```

- `this.pixiOverlay` is added as one layer
- then in rest of program we reuse `this.pixiOverlay`
- also we reuse `this.pixiContainer` because it is returned from `utils` - see:

```
let container = utils.getContainer()  // <-- this is our "this.pixiContainer"
...
container.addChild(marker)
renderer.render(container)
```

## Bonus: Triangles

Now you can add many triangles - one per each click.

Note: triangles do not change scale - this is a difference compared to hamsters.

Comment: thanks for your answer. +1 but if you click multiple times on the 'add image' you will not that some of the hamsters disappears in favor of a new hamster; this is not my expected output. Why does it happened and how to avoid it? I would like to have a hamster per click. Thanks again!

Comment: @ProcolHarum updated my answer - please recheck :)

Comment: THANK YOU!!! learned something new today.

Comment: glad to help :)